# cambiar nombre a la variable en el request o en el controlador (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, variables

después de enviar un formulario tengo las siguientes variables

```
        'meo-tool-url' => 'required|string',
        'google-maps-url' => 'required|string',
        'state' => 'required|integer',
        'recipients' => 'required|string',
        'location-id' => 'required',
        'business-types' => 'required|integer',
```

como pueden observar, están todas las que tienen palabras separadas con guiones medios, lo cual me genera conflicto porque en la base de datos todas tienen guiones bajos
por un tema del formato de mi equipo de trabajo con javascript, me veo obligado a utilizar guiones medios para los campos en las vistas, así que no puedo cambiarlos desde ahí a guiones bajos

esta es la función donde intento hacer los renombres y no puedo

```
public function saveDigestReport ($request){
    $digestReport->business_type_id = $request->business-types;
    $digestReport->meo_tool_url = $request->meo-tool-url;
    $digestReport->google_maps_url = $request->google-maps-url;
    $digestReport->location_id = $request->location-id;
    $digestReport = new Meo($request->all());
    $digestReport->save();
    return $digestReport;
```

}

el IDE me marca problemas con las palabras que tengo separadas con guiones[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @JuanRivera gracias por la respuesta amigo, al final después de un poco de toqueteo con el debug lo hice así $request->business_type_id = request("business-types"); y cambié todo el $digestReport por $request

Answer (score 1):

En caso de que quieras una función que convierta todas las llaves en formato kebab-case a snake_case

```php
function sanitizarNombres(&$array) {
    foreach ($array as $clave => $valor) {
        if (strpos($clave, '-')) {
            $nuevaClave = str_replace('-', '_', $clave);
            $array[$nuevaClave] = $valor;
            unset($array[$clave]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias, me será útil

Answer (score 0):

finalmente despues de muchas "prueba y error" me funcionó así

```
    public function saveDigestReport ($request){
        $request = new Meo($request->all());
        $request->business_type_id = request("business-types");
        $request->meo_tool_url = request("meo-tool-url");
        $request->google_maps_url = request("google-maps-url");
        $request->location_id = request("location-id");;
        $request->save();
        return $request;
   }
```

Comment: Aunque esta bien, no se trata de prueba y error, te recomiendo leer la documentacion del `request`, ahi te dice como tomar esos parametros [HTTP Requests-Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests)